# Flyout Menu windows phone 8.1 on hold Listview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How can I show a `flyout` menu when use hold an item on a `listview`? I have tried but the hold method reference the `listview` and not the item it self.

Comment: `listview` is not applicable for WP8. Are you talking about WP8.1 then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may subscribe to Item's Template *Holding* event. For example like this:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Holding="Grid_Holding" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton"
                            Text="Edit"
                            Click="EditButton_Click"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="DeleteButton"
                            Text="Delete"
                            Click="DeleteButton_Click"/>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And in the code behind, show the flyout:

```cs
private void Grid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
    // If you need the clicked element:
    // Item whichOne = senderElement.DataContext as Item;
    FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);
    flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
}

private async void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // get the clicked element:
    Item datacontext = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Item;
    await new MessageDialog("Edit").ShowAsync();
}
```

You may also do it with *Behaviours* if you like. You will also find some help at [Igrali's blog post](http://igrali.com/2014/04/28/show-context-menu-using-menuflyout-windows-phone-8-1/).

Comment: @Romasz - using this whole holded item pops out.Is there any property to keep item in its place ?

Comment: @RohitGarg I don't know. I think it's also a nice question, so just ask it on SO.